# DC.js compositeChart with two lineChart both representing average value by date

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to create DC.js chart with two lines each representing average value by date.

I believe the way to do this is to use DC.js `compositeChart` and create two lineCharts to put into it, and then use <del>`reducio()`</del>  `group.reduce(add, remove, initial)` to get the average amounts.

My question is where does the conditional logic go? How/where do I conditionally use this:

```
var group = dimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
```

to calculate average for records with `d.PPCC === "PPCC"` and another average for records with `d.PPCC === "Other"`?

I have tried two ways neither of which is working for me.

This is first try:

```
var bounce30DaysPPCC = function(d) { if (d.PPCC === "PPCC") 
{ dateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial); 
} else { dateDim.group().reduce(0); } };

var bounce30DaysOther = function(d) { if (d.PPCC === "Other") 
{ dateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial); 
} else { dateDim.group().reduce(0); } };
```

which produces this error:

```
dc.js:4017 Uncaught TypeError: layer.group.all is not a function
```

This is second try:

```
var bounce30DaysPPCC = dateDim.group().reduce( function(d) { if (d.PPCC === "PPCC") 
{ return reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial; } else { return 0; }});

var bounce30DaysOther = dateDim.group().reduceSum( function(d) { if (d.PPCC === "Other") 
{ return reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial; } else { return 0; } });
```

which also produces an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: reduceInitial is not a function
```

Here is my full javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // get csv data 
    d3.csv("merged.csv", function(data) {

    // get csv data and format date
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.sessions = +d.sessions;
        d.ad_requests = +d.ad_requests;
        d.bounceRate = +d.bounceRate;
        d.clicks = +d.clicks;
        d.earnings = +d.earnings;
        d.newUsers = +d.newUsers;
        d.sessionDuration = +d.sessionDuration;
        d.sessionsPerUser = +d.sessionsPerUser;
        d.twitterSessions = +d.twitterSessions;
        d.users = +d.users;
    });

    // setup crossfilter
    var ndx  = crossfilter(data);

    // create dimension
    var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["date"]; });

    // create data groups
    var bounce30DaysPPCC = function(d) { if (d.PPCC === "PPCC") 
    { dateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial); 
    } else { dateDim.group().reduce(0); } };

    var bounce30DaysOther = function(d) { if (d.PPCC === "Other") 
    { dateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial); 
    } else { dateDim.group().reduce(0); } };

    // create min and max dates to limit chart x axis values
    var minDateTime = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-30));

    var maxDateTime = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+1));

    // create chart     
    BounceChart30Day = dc.compositeChart("#bounce-chart-30day");

    // create two line charts to put into composite chart
    var ppccLine = dc.lineChart(BounceChart30Day)
    .group(bounce30DaysPPCC)    

    var otherLine = dc.lineChart(BounceChart30Day)
    .group(bounce30DaysOther)

    // create composite chart
    BounceChart30Day
    .height(50)
    .width(450)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 5, left: 35})
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .brushOn(false)
    .elasticY(true)
    .compose([ppccLine, otherLine])
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDateTime, maxDateTime]))
    .yAxis().ticks(3);

    // create value accessor to calculate averages
    BounceChart30Day.valueAccessor(function(p) { 
    return p.value.count > 0 ? p.value.total / p.value.count : 0; });

    // create add, remove, initial reduce functions
    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
      ++p.count;
      p.total += v.bounceRate;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
      --p.count;
      p.total -= v.bounceRate;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
      return {count: 0, total: 0};
    }

    // render chart
    dc.renderAll();

</script>
```

Comment: You need to do the assignment inside your 'if' statements. 'var a = if(b) { 1 } else { 2 }' results in 'a' being 'undefined' IIRC. If you are using reductio, then look at the filter option: https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-b-filter-b-i-filterfn-i-

Comment: My first try does it in `if` statement but not sure how specifically to refer to `group.reduce(add, remove, initial)` within the `if` statement. Sorry I removed the mistaken reference to `"reducio()"` I am not using it / `reductio()`

Comment: Your reduce call looks fine. Your problem is that nothing ever gets assigned to 'bounce30DaysOther', I believe.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include a few things in my code. Just added the add, remove, initial reduce functions, and the dimension variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the data within your reduce functions. So make your reduce functions look something like this:

```
// create add, remove, initial reduce functions
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  if (v.PPCC === "PPCC") {
    ++p.PPCCcount;
    p.PPCCtotal += v.bounceRate;
  } else if(v.PPCC === "Other") {
    ++p.Othercount;
    p.Othertotal += v.bounceRate;
  }
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  if (v.PPCC === "PPCC") {
    --p.PPCCcount;
    p.PPCCtotal -= v.bounceRate;
  } else if(v.PPCC === "Other") {
    --p.Othercount;
    p.Othertotal -= v.bounceRate;
  }
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return { PPCCcount: 0, PPCCtotal: 0, Othercount: 0, Othertotal: 0};
}
```

Then just create your groups as normal:

```
var bounce30DaysPPCC = dateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
var bounce30DaysOther = dateDim.group().reduceSum(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
```

Everything else looks pretty much OK at first glance. You'll just need to update your `valueAccessor` functions to get at the new property names on the groups.

Comment: Javascript question: should `d.PPCC` be accessible without specifying `function (d)` in the `reduceAdd` and `reduceRemove` functions ?

Comment: No, copy/paste typo on my part. I've changed it to `v`, which it should have been in the first place.

Comment: Great thanks. I put `console.log(v.date, v.PPCC, v.bounceRate)` before `if (v.PPCC === "PPCC") {` which successfully prints date, PPCC, bounceRate values in console. But then I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PPCC' of undefined` when it gets to `if (v.PPCC === "PPCC") {`  If it can print `v.PPCC` to console, why is `v.PPCC` suddenly undefined in the `if` statement?

Comment: I don't see any reason for that. I think for this one you may need to put together a working example (on JSFiddle or a similar site) or share the full code and data you are running on.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with inline 4 rows of JSON formatted data   [https://jsfiddle.net/curtisp/7frw79q6/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/curtisp/7frw79q6/1/)

Comment: Ok got it. I wasn't putting `value` in the `valueAccessor` variables eg was using `p.Othercount`  instead of `p.value.Othercount` that fixed it for me. I updated JSFiddle but it isn't working though, likely the inline JSON data isn't setup correctly.

Comment: You'll want to link to your latest JSFiddle whenever you have a new problem. In this case, take a look at your browser console. You need to load d3.js (version 3, not 4) before dc.js.

Comment: Thanks for help. JSFiddle linked above is working now.

Comment: Here is updated JSFiddle link with working solution [https://jsfiddle.net/curtisp/7frw79q6/](https://jsfiddle.net/curtisp/7frw79q6/)